# Flutter ARCore view issue

Tags: flutter, arcore

ArCoreView looks like not working after upgrading compile SDK version to 33.
Output shows that arcore are detecting some surfaces but in application its looks like empty screen.
I'd tried arcore_flutter_plugn and ar_flutter_plugin, and both are showing same issue.
Is it some fix for this issue? or maybe its possible to compile this part for older sdk version?

I'h tried to update libraries imports, and other compile versions